# How to return the value of a promise to a function that requires static data to be returned?

Tags: angular, algolia

I'm working on an Ionic 2 app that has an [autocomplete](https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete) component that I'm using that utilizes a function which requires either a static array of data or an observable to be returned.

I'm using Algolia to handle searches and when a user starts typing, I want to query Algolia and return the results to the autocomplete. The main problem is that since the Algolia call returns a promise, I have no way to get that data from `.then()` to be returned from the function. Is there a straight forward way to do this?

```
Here's my function:

  getResults(keyword:string) {
    return this.genresIndex.search(keyword).then(result => {
      return result.hits; // <-- this would just be an array of results
    })
  }
```

Here is the component HTML:

```
<ion-auto-complete [dataProvider]="_genres"></ion-auto-complete>
```

the `[dataProvider]` references the provider that contains the function `getResults(keyword)`, so it'd be like `this._genres.getResults(keyword)` kind of thing.

I'm not exactly sure about a way around this, since the module that I'm utilizing has a pretty set way of grabbing results from an external data source.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: return an observable, `return Observable.from(this.genresIndex.search(..).then(...))`

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi you are a wonderful human being and I wish I could hug you. I was struggling with this for hours. Thankyou so much!

Comment: you're welcome) I've posted it as an answer so you can maybe accept it as a replacement for hugging :)

Comment: Absolutely :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which requires either a static array of data or an observable to be
>   returned

So you can wrap the promise into an observable and return it:

```
return Observable.from(this.genresIndex.search(..).then(...))
```